# how to fix error 406 rarely return from a server

Tags: php, server

I use domain.com host and I had seen 406 error return several times. Then when I refresh the browsers, my webpage display correctly. I want to know that is the server problem or my code problem and how can I prevent it happen in the future?

Comment: I hate the way people vote down without any comment.

Answer (score 1):

Your operation did not fail.

Your backend service is saying that the response type it is returning is not provided in the Accept HTTP header in your Client request.

Ref: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields

Find out the response (content type) returned by Service.
Provide this (content type) in your request Accept header.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_status_code -> 406

Comment: thank!.. I do know and read all of the articles about it but don't know what causes the problem. because it rarely returns, so I can not tract it.